# Probability Differentiation

Tags: probability

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdK1W.png
I don't understand how $$F_X(y^{\frac{1}{n}}) $$ is equal to $$ y^{\frac{1}{n}} $$
and when you take the derivative to get the density function shouldn't it be 
$$ \frac{1}{n} y^{\frac{1}{n}-1}f_X(y^{\frac{1}{n}}) $$

Answer (score 1):

As $ X $ is uniformly $(0, 1) $-distributed, we have $$ F_X (u) = u $$
for all $ u \in (0, 1) $.

Comment: I don't get. I understand that it's uniformly distributed but why does $$ F_X(y^{\frac{1}{n}}) $$ = $$ y^{\frac{1}{n}} $$ .

Comment: @Undergradstudent Try to obtain the CDF of a $(0,1)$ RV. Hint: Its pdf is $1$ in that interval, $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Okay I think I get it since it's uniform then the probability is the same throughout the interval. So P(X<y^(1/n) is equal to y^(1/n). I think.